# Is there any WordPress way to get all categories for some selected posts?

Tags: terms, categories

I want to get all categories of some selected posts.
For example, I have post IDs like 1,2,3. Post 1,2,3 has categories {cat, dog}, {dog, mouse}, {mouse} respectively. I want a category list which includes {cat, dog, mouse}.

I have looked into two WP functions,
`get_terms:` does not allow me to supply post ids
`wp_get_post_terms:` this only returns terms for a single post

I have found two ways to achieve the same:

**1. Loop** 
Get the post ids first then use a loop to get categories for each post. That is too many queries when there are too many posts.

**2. Custom query**
the following query also gives me desired result. but it's not really a WP's style to run a custom query. I really want to avoid this solution.

```
select * from sh_7_terms
where term_id in (
    select distinct(sh_7_terms.term_id)
    from sh_7_terms, sh_7_term_taxonomy, sh_7_term_relationships, sh_7_posts
    where 
        sh_7_terms.term_id = sh_7_term_taxonomy.term_id AND
        sh_7_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = sh_7_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND
        sh_7_term_relationships.object_id = sh_7_posts.ID AND
        sh_7_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat' and 
        sh_7_posts.ID IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
)
```

**Question:**
Is there any other optimized solution out there?

Comment: Well, what do you need returned? If it's just IDs - multiple queries won't matter because they'll be fast. If you need all things or Objects then creating a function that queries is your next best bet. AFAIK WP doesn't have a quick or efficient way to get all assigned categories from multiple posts.

Comment: I think you are right, looks like multiple quires is the only option I got. But still wanted to hear some other opinions.

Comment: I'd be happier if someone who better understood the process confirmed or explained with more specifics and higher confidence, but, if I understand correctly, since wp_get_post_terms() relies on the $wpdb class, I believe that the result is cached - not just the given array, but the entire column - meaning that you wouldn't be performing a unique new query every time you got the terms for a different post. Assembling the unique category names would be straightforward PHP after that. Or have I misunderstood your actual concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter [`wp_get_object_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) - it accepts an array of object IDs and retrieves all of their (unique) attached terms:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( [ 1, 2, 3 ], 'category' );
foreach ( $terms as $term )
    echo "$term->name<br />";
```

Comment: $post_ids = array( 1,2,3 ) ;

$cat_names = wp_get_object_terms( $post_ids, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) ;

Comment: Thanks TheDeadMedic. That's the function I was looking for. Cheers :)